# How Entity Framework Updates Entity after DB update call

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have class Customer and Order class.
Customer class has Order Class And DeliveryAddress class as virtual property

```
class Customer
{
    public int custId{get;set;}
    public string custName{get;set;}
    [ForiegnKey("custId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders{get;set;}
    [ForiegnKey("custId")]
    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryAddress> Addresses{get;set;}
}
class Order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int custId{get;set;}
    public string OrdDescription{get;set;}
    [ForiegnKey("custId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer{get;set;}
}
public class DomainService
{
    public void CreateAndSave()
    {
        Customer A = new Customer();
        mycontext.Entity(A).State= EntityState.Added;
        Order ord1= new Order();
        mycontext.Entity(ord1).State= EntityState.Added;
        Order ord2= new Order();
        mycontext.Entity(ord2).State= EntityState.Added;
        DeliveryAddress adr1= new DeliveryAddress();
        mycontext.Entity(adr1).State= EntityState.Added;
        DeliveryAddress adr2= new DeliveryAddress();
        mycontext.Entity(adr2).State= EntityState.Added;
        A.DeliveryAddress.Add(adr1);
        A.DeliveryAddress.Add(adr2);
        mycontext.SaveChanges();
    //After added records into Customer and Order table.I immediately call stored procedure which will update few columns in the newly added records
    }
}
```

My Question is how do i update the in-memory instance of Customer and Order class instances in mycontext to get reflected with the changes done at stored procedure.
I have tried using Reload method but A.Orders shows count of 4, 2 records from above code and another 2 as Dynamic Proxies objects.
Another problem with dynamic proxies are when i update columns in one of the record in DeliveryAddress table, it is trying to update all column in Order table.
Please help how to reload and track object in in-memory so that i can proceed with further update using context in EF

Comment: IMO, the safest method would be to re-query EF for the newly updated data (i.e. using a Find method), as if retrieving the data for the first time.

Comment: I have read in some articles that Find method will pick entity object from.cache but not from database